# SQL SELECT and PHP retrive speed INT vs TINYINT vs VARCHAR vs ENUM?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, postgresql, select

I'm in the process of creating a table then display records and it made me wonder.

If I store, say 'Eating Habits' that has a make (Vegetarian, Non-Vegetarian and Eggetarian), will it make any difference on the query speed if I store the 'eating_habits' as an **int** or **tinyint** or **varchar** or **enum** type.

So is using **int**  **[approach 1]**

```
// to select records  
SELECT * FROM table WHERE eating_habits = 2 AND ...;

//for display in php  
foreach($all_records AS $key => $val) {
if($val['eating_habits'] == 1)
    echo 'Vegetarian'; 
elseif($val['eating_habits'] == 2)
    echo 'Non-Vegetarian';
else
 echo 'Eggetarian';
}
```

Faster/slower than - using **tinyint** **[approach 2]**

```
 // script will same as above aproach 1
  ....
```

Faster/slower than - using **int or tinyint with join****[approach 3]**

```
// to select records  
 SELECT *.t1  FROM table1 as t1 join table2 as t2 on ti.eat_habit_id=t2.eating_habits 
 WHERE t2.eating_habits = 2 AND ...;
//for display in php  
 foreach($all_records AS $key => $val) {
  echo $val['eating_habits'];
  }
```

Faster/slower than - using **varchar** **[approach 4]**

```
// to select records  
SELECT * FROM table WHERE eating_habits = 'Non-Vegetarian' AND ...;

//for display in php  
foreach($all_records AS $key => $val) {
echo $val['eating_habits'];
}
```

Faster/slower than - using **enum** **[approach 5]**

```
  // script will same as above approach 3
  .....
```

from the above 5 approach which will give me the faster result to search, fetch and display records in php page ?

Comment: whats stopping you benchmarking it?

Comment: i did not get you ? could you elaborate ?

Comment: Always design with normalisation in mind. After the first design iteration the schema must be as normalised as possible. Only optimise after you **has proven** that what you're trying to do is worth optimising. And to address your original question: it does not matter. At all.

Comment: @zerkms, how can i optimize data in my case should i create 2 tables and join it or use only 1 table or else other?

Comment: @amitgupta I'm sure you haven't read my comment. Why do you need to optimise it at first place?

Comment: @zerkms, sorry i mean to say how can i normalize data in my case should i create 2 tables and join it or use only 1 table or else other?

Comment: What do you know about normalisation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization 3rd normal form is the good compromise https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88326/discussion-between-amit-gupta-and-zerkms).

Comment: You're asking the wrong questions. Unless you have a specific performance issue you're encountering, you should be focusing on "how do I make my database design easy to understand, use and maintain" not "which data types go faster in this microbenchmark".

Answer (score 1):

The speed difference is insignificant.  The biggest cost is reading the record.  For that, shorter records is *usually* better for performance.  Then a 1-byte `ENUM` as you suggested is the smallest.

A drawback to `ENUM` is that if you add a new option, you need to `ALTER` the table.

Similarly a 1-byte `TINYINT` is marginally faster than a 4-byte `INT`.

If you are only going to have a few thousand rows, simply make it `VARCHAR(..)` and don't worry about it.  If you expect to have hundreds of millions of rows, *do* pick the datatype carefully.

Comment: in future its going to millions of row , and the eating_habits will contain only 3 kinds of values always. because eating habits is universal truth only three (Vegetarian, Non-Vegetarian and eggetarian). i want to search and display the records so i want to know which data type will give me faster result in this case?

Comment: @amitgupta no one can tell you what problems will you have when you have millions of rows. But since you ask such questions it's fair to assume that you will experience some more severe problems much earlier. And they will not be caused by int vs enum choice.

Comment: @zerkms , yes you are right , i am ready to face other problems i just want to take care of creation of database now by choosing the best at this time. if i choose 'enum' then it will easy to display the records also but in case of 'int' i have to perform join or some manual cheekings so after that this question came in mind which approch will give more fast result including displaying the records in browser also ?

Comment: 3 values, unlikely to every add a 4th.  So `ENUM` sees to be best -- easy to read/write, efficient (1 byte), etc.  The table may be only 1GB.

Comment: I've seen it time and time again that people design tables and don't keep in mind that the table will grow. It would always be best to design the table properly and use the most efficient data field types.

Comment: Adding a new option on the end of an ENUM is a very efficient ALTER.